# Use .Call() to send an s4 object to a C struct

Tags: c, r, rcpp, r-s4

I would like to pass a simple s4 object into C and turn it into an simple struct. I'm picturing R code like

```
setClass("MyClass", slots = list(x = "numeric", y = "integer"))
r_instance = new("MyClass", x = rnorm(5), y = as.integer(1:10))
dyn.load("parse.so")
.Call("parse", r_instance)
```

with `parse.c`

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <Rmath.h>

typedef struct {
  double x;
  int y;
} MyStruct;

SEXP parse(SEXP r_instance){
  MyStruct c_instance = MAKE_S4_INTO_STRUCT(r_instance);
  printf("%g %d\n", c_instance->x[0], c_instance->y[0]);
  return R_NilValue;
}
```

Is there a `MAKE_S4_INTO_STRUCT` function that would make this work? I haven't found an answer in [Hadley's C interface page](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html) or the [R extensions manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Classes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, the *"I wish there was a pony"* approach does not always work.

But by creating `as<>()` and `wrap()` converters from Rcpp you could build yourself such a facility. See the existing S4 converters examples 
[here](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/sparse-matrix-coercion/) or
[here](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/as-and-wrap-for-sparse-matrices/) for inspiration.

In a nutshell, your `struct` does not yet exist as either an R type or an Rcpp type, so you will have to provide the mapping. Once you do, things should get peachy as the converters you add will get called "on demand".

That said, writing such converters is probably not what you should do on your first day with Rcpp ...

Comment: Those examples pointed me in the right direction, and I think I figured out what I need to know about s4 and Rcpp. It turns out that I was asking the wrong question, all I think I'll need is access to s4 slots inside C++ with something like `S4 obj(arg); double x* = REAL(obj.slot("x"));`. Now, I'm trying to [make Rcpp and CUDA play nicely together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628333/building-a-tiny-r-package-with-cuda-and-rcpp).

Comment: Cool. You can also use `Rcpp::as<double>(...)` instead of `REAL(...)`.