# R CMD check warning with CUDA *.cu files

Tags: c++, c, r, bioconductor

I'm building a [tiny R package](https://github.com/wlandau/rcppcuda) that uses Rcpp and CUDA. It's a learning exercise to help me build a bigger package to submit to Bioconductor. The package installs and runs just fine on the Linux machine I describe in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628333/building-a-tiny-r-package-with-cuda-and-rcpp/30711681?noredirect=1#comment49536174_30711681). However, when I run `R CMD check` on the tarball, I get a warning.

```
$ R CMD check rcppcuda_0.0.tar.gz 
* using log directory ‘/home/landau/rcppcuda.Rcheck’
* using R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
* using platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)
* using session charset: UTF-8
* checking for file ‘rcppcuda/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* checking extension type ... Package
* this is package ‘rcppcuda’ version ‘0.0’
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... OK
* checking if this is a source package ... WARNING
Subdirectory ‘src’ contains:
  someCUDAcode.cu
These are unlikely file names for src files.
* checking if there is a namespace ... OK
* checking for executable files ... OK
* checking for hidden files and directories ... OK
* checking for portable file names ... OK
* checking for sufficient/correct file permissions ... OK
* checking whether package ‘rcppcuda’ can be installed ... OK
* checking installed package size ... OK
* checking package directory ... OK
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking top-level files ... OK
* checking for left-over files ... OK
* checking index information ... OK
* checking package subdirectories ... OK
* checking R files for non-ASCII characters ... OK
* checking R files for syntax errors ... OK
* checking whether the package can be loaded ... OK
* checking whether the package can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK
* checking whether the package can be unloaded cleanly ... OK
* checking whether the namespace can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK
* checking whether the namespace can be unloaded cleanly ... OK
* checking loading without being on the library search path ... OK
* checking dependencies in R code ... OK
* checking S3 generic/method consistency ... OK
* checking replacement functions ... OK
* checking foreign function calls ... OK
* checking R code for possible problems ... OK
* checking Rd files ... OK
* checking Rd metadata ... OK
* checking Rd cross-references ... OK
* checking for missing documentation entries ... OK
* checking for code/documentation mismatches ... OK
* checking Rd \usage sections ... OK
* checking Rd contents ... OK
* checking for unstated dependencies in examples ... OK
* checking line endings in C/C++/Fortran sources/headers ... OK
* checking line endings in Makefiles ... OK
* checking compilation flags in Makevars ... OK
* checking for GNU extensions in Makefiles ... OK
* checking for portable use of $(BLAS_LIBS) and $(LAPACK_LIBS) ... OK
* checking compiled code ... OK
* checking examples ... NONE
* checking PDF version of manual ... OK
* DONE

Status: 1 WARNING
See
  ‘/home/landau/rcppcuda.Rcheck/00check.log’
for details.

$
```

This warning, also present in the bigger package I'm building, prevents me from submitting to Bioconductor. Warnings in `R CMD check` automatically disqualify me. Sadly, `nvcc` requires a `.cu` extension on each CUDA file, so I can't rename `*.cu` to `*.c` or `*.cpp`. Does anyone know how to tell R that `*.cu` files are legitimate source files?

Comment: You should speak with the people at BIoconductor (e.g., through the [contact information](http://bioconductor.org/developers/package-submission/#contact-info) on the bottom of the page describing package submission); they are unlikely to disallow a package with a warning that is not justified. In the current case you'd probably want to be explicit about the consequences of using CUDA for package building and portability (will end-users need to install CUDA headers and compilers? Does this extra requirement result in worth-while gain?)

Comment: The page [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/check.html) indicates that only `specified files and directories` are allowed at the "top" level, but you can move files into `inst` if you need them to be installed...check out the section for `Checking top-level files`. If this works, feel free to answer the question yourself!

Comment: nvcc *doesn't* require a `.cu` extension to compile CUDA code. That is the default behaviour, but there is a specific command line option to manually set language rather than inferring from the file extension

Comment: What is that option? I've looked at the `nvcc` manual, but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: Also, @Martin_Morgan, yes, I have been wondering about CUDA and Bioconductor. Users need to have CUDA installed, as well as CUDA-enabled NVIDIA GPUs attached to their machines, and this special software and hardware is not very common. The package will not compile with regular gcc/g++ tools. However, that's part of the design. CUDA adds a major speedup, without which the package would likely not be practical. When the time comes, I will contact Bioconductor about this portability issue.

Comment: Never mind, @talonmies. I just needed to change the source to `.cpp` files to add `-x cu` to my `nvcc` flags. Thanks! If you post your comment as an answer, I'll upvote and check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the default behaviour of nvcc is to automatically deduce language from filename extension (so that CUDA code is expected to be contained in a `.cu` extension file), this is not a fixed requirement. nvcc supports the `-x` flag to manually set language for a given compilation unit, so you could use pass  `-x cu` to a source file containing CUDA code with a `.cpp` extension and the compilation will work correctly.

Whether this is advisable from a maintainability perspective is a decision you will have to make. But it should solve your immediate problem.