# Using devtools to build an R package that imports cuda code

Tags: r, cuda, rcpp, devtools

I'm trying to utilize `gpu` machines in oder to improve performance of a matrix multiplication operation.

I tried to make sense of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628333/building-a-tiny-r-package-with-cuda-and-rcpp) and utilize `cuda` code from [this repos](https://github.com/lzhengchun/matrix-cuda) and build it all in an `R` `package` using `devtools`.

What I did is write a `cuda` file named `matrixMultiplication.cu`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define BLOCK_SIZE 16


__global__ void runGpuMatrixMult(double *a, double *b, double *c, int m, int n, int k)
{
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int sum = 0;
    if( col < k && row < m)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            sum += a[row * n + i] * b[i * k + col];
        }
        c[row * k + col] = sum;
    }
}

extern "C"
void gpuMatrixMult(double &A, double &B, double &C, int& m, int& n, int& k) {
    // allocate memory in host RAM
    double *h_A, *h_B, *h_C;
    cudaMallocHost((void **) &h_A, sizeof(int)*m*n);
    cudaMallocHost((void **) &h_B, sizeof(int)*n*k);
    cudaMallocHost((void **) &h_C, sizeof(int)*m*k);

    // Allocate memory space on the device
    int *d_A, *d_B, *d_C;
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_A, sizeof(int)*m*n);
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_B, sizeof(int)*n*k);
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_C, sizeof(int)*m*k);

    // copy matrix A and B from host to device memory
    cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, sizeof(int)*m*n, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_B, h_B, sizeof(int)*n*k, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    unsigned int grid_rows = (m + BLOCK_SIZE - 1) / BLOCK_SIZE;
    unsigned int grid_cols = (k + BLOCK_SIZE - 1) / BLOCK_SIZE;
    dim3 dimGrid(grid_cols, grid_rows);
    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);

    // Launch kernel
    runGpuMatrixMult<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C, m, n, k);

    // Transfer results from device to host
    cudaMemcpy(h_C, d_C, sizeof(int)*m*k, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaThreadSynchronize();

    // free memory
    cudaFree(d_A);
    cudaFree(d_B);
    cudaFree(d_C);
    cudaFreeHost(h_A);
    cudaFreeHost(h_B);
    cudaFreeHost(h_C);
    return 0;
}
```

Then a `cpp` file named `matrixUtils.cpp`:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

extern "C"
void gpuMatrixMult(double const&A, double const&B, double const& C, int& m, int& n, int& k);


//' gpuMatrixMultCaller calls matrixMultiplication.cu::gpuMatrixMult
//'
//' @export
//[[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP gpuMatrixMultCaller(double const& A, double const& B, double& C, int m, int n, int k) {
  gpuMatrixMult(A, B, C, m, n, k);
  return R_NilValue;
}
```

Finally, I have an R file named `utils.R` which has a wrapper `function` that calls `gpuMatrixMultCaller`:

```
#' gpuMatrixMultWrapper calls matrixUtils.cpp::gpuMatrixMultCaller which runs a GPU matrix multiplication
#' Returns the product of the input matrices
gpuMatrixMultWrapper <- function(A,B)
{
  m <- nrow(A)
  n <- ncol(A)
  k <- ncol(B)
  C <- bigmemory::deepcopy(A)
  gpuMatrixMultCaller(A, B, C, m, n, k)
  return(C)
}
```

When I run `devtools::document` I get this error:

```
Error in dyn.load(dllfile) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/code/packages/utils/src/utils.so':
  /home/code/packages/utils/src/utils.so: undefined symbol: gpuMatrixMult
```

The `NAMESPACE` file does have: `useDynLib(utils)` at the bottom line and in the `DESCRIPTION` file I specify: `LinkingTo: Rcpp, RcppArmadillo`

So my questions are:

1. Is it even possible to build an `R` `pacakge` which imports `cuda` code? using `devtools`? If not should the `cuda` part simply be coded in the `cpp` file?
2. If so what am I missing? I tried adding `#include <cuda.h>` in `matrixUtils.cpp` but got: `fatal error: cuda.h: No such file or directory`

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try to Build the shared object file utils.so with tcc, which is linked to cuda. Then ```dyn.load("utils.so")```.

Comment: Why are you trying to use C linkage for?

Comment: I didn't make any decision about that. It may be devtool's default.

Comment: Eh? You wrote the CUDA code, and I presume you added `extern "C"` all the way through it. Why did *you* choose to do that?