# ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RCUDA’

Tags: r

I couldn't install RCUDA  package in R. My R version is 3.4.4.

> package ‘RCUDA’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)

I have installed the dependent libraries like,

```
library(RAutoGenRunTime)
library(methods)
library(utils)
```

Also i have tried installing using zip file.

> enumConverters.c: In function ‘Renum_convert_CUcomputemode’:
>   enumConverters.c:781:14: error: ‘CU_COMPUTEMODE_EXCLUSIVE’ undeclared
>   (first use in this function)
>            case CU_COMPUTEMODE_EXCLUSIVE:
>                 ^ enumConverters.c:781:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
>   /usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:159: recipe for target 'enumConverters.o'
>   failed make: *** [enumConverters.o] Error 1 ERROR: compilation failed
>   for package ‘RCUDA’
>   * removing ‘/home/achu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/RCUDA’

my CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          9.0 / 8.0

I have tried different methods for installing as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa. But its not working. Anyone knows what is the problem with this installation?

Comment: Are you referring to https://github.com/duncantl/RCUDA? That project does not look very active. Do you specifically need `RCUDA` or are you just trying to use the GPU from R?

Comment: @Ralf stubner : I am trying to run my R code on CUDA. so that i think i have to use RCUDA package in R. i have referred github.com/duncantl/RCUDA.

Comment: There are other possibilities. See the GPU section of https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html or https://www.daqana.org/rcpparrayfire/.

Comment: See also the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/30628333 for additional suggestions. It is worth noting that most CUDA packages on CRAN have been archived, though.