Error when trying to compile an R package with CUDA and Rcpp
I'm building a small R package using CUDA and Rcpp as a learning exercise (using Building a tiny R package with CUDA and Rcpp as inspiration). It includes a single function that takes a device ID and returns a few properties for that device.
This package compiles without any issues in WSL2 (Ubuntu 22.04, R 4.4.1, CUDA/nvcc 12.3) and returns the device properties as expected. To do so I'm using the Makevars files as below:
CUDA_HOME = /usr/local/cuda-12.3
R_HOME = /home/killianmelsen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.4
R_INC = /usr/share/R/include
RCPP_INC = $(R_HOME)/Rcpp/include
NVCC = $(CUDA_HOME)/bin/nvcc
CUDA_INC = $(CUDA_HOME)/include
PKG_LIBS = -L$(CUDA_HOME)/lib64 -Wl,-rpath,$(CUDA_HOME)/lib64 -lcudart
NVCC_FLAGS = -x cu -Xcompiler "-fPIC" -gencode arch=compute_86,code=sm_86 -I$(R_INC)

### Define objects
sharedlibs = code.o RcppExports.o
sources = code.cpp RcppExports.cpp
OBJECTS = $(sharedlibs)

all : cudar.so
cudar.so: $(OBJECTS)

%.o: %.cpp $(sources)
    $(NVCC) $(NVCC_FLAGS) -I$(CUDA_INC) -I$(R_INC) -I$(RCPP_INC) $< -c

The code.cpp file includes the C++ as well as CUDA code. I simply tried "translating" the Makevars to a Makevars.win version that might work with Windows, but it didn't:
CUDA_HOME = "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.3"
R_HOME = "C:/Users/Killian/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2"
R_INC = "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2/include"
RCPP_INC = $(R_HOME)/Rcpp/include
NVCC = $(CUDA_HOME)/bin/nvcc
CUDA_INC = $(CUDA_HOME)/include
PKG_LIBS = -L$(CUDA_HOME)/lib/x64 -Wl,-rpath,$(CUDA_HOME)/lib/x64 -lcudart
NVCC_FLAGS = -x cu -Xcompiler "-fPIC" -gencode arch=compute_86,code=sm_86 -I$(R_INC)

### Define objects
sharedlibs = code.obj RcppExports.obj
sources = code.cpp RcppExports.cpp
OBJECTS = $(sharedlibs)

all : cudar.dll
cudar.dll: $(OBJECTS)

%.obj: %.cpp $(sources)
    $(NVCC) $(NVCC_FLAGS) -I$(CUDA_INC) -I$(R_INC) -I$(RCPP_INC) $< -c

At first I got an error that cl.exe couldn't be found by nvcc, but it seems I fixed that by adding the folder containing cl.exe to PATH. At this point I get the following error:
── R CMD INSTALL ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
─  installing *source* package 'cudar' ...
   ** using staged installation
   ** libs
   "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.3"/bin/nvcc -x cu -Xcompiler "-fPIC" -gencode arch=compute_86,code=sm_86 -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2/include" -I"C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.3"/include -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2/include" -I"C:/Users/Killian/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2"/Rcpp/include code.cpp -c
   cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fPIC'
   code.cpp
   C:/Users/Killian/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/Rcpp/include\Rcpp/platform/compiler.h(43): fatal error C1189: #error:  "This compiler is not supported"
   code.cpp
   make: *** [Makevars.win:27: code.obj] Error 2
   ERROR: compilation failed for package 'cudar'
─  removing 'C:/Users/Killian/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpgnlywh/devtools_install_44583263584d/cudar'
Error in `(function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE, …`:
! System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed
---
Exit status: 1
stdout & stderr: <printed>
---
Type .Last.error to see the more details.

I've uploaded the package to GitHub in case that helps: https://github.com/KillianMelsen/cudar/tree/main
What's going wrong here? Ideally I'd like to use CUDA in R within Windows as well.
Edit: I was able to get the linking to run by moving around some quotes (https://github.com/KillianMelsen/cudar/tree/split). However, there's a bunch of errors coming from the linking:
── R CMD INSTALL ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
─  installing *source* package 'cudar' ...
   ** using staged installation
   ** libs
   g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2/include" -I"C:/Users/Killian/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/Rcpp/include" -std=gnu++11 -c CPP.cpp -o CPP.obj
   g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2/include" -I"C:/Users/Killian/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/Rcpp/include" -std=gnu++11 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.obj
   "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.3/bin/nvcc" -x cu -Xcompiler "-O2" -gencode arch=compute_86,code=sm_86 -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2/include" -I"C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.3/include" -c CUDA.cu -o CUDA.obj
   CUDA.cu
   tmpxft_00004bcc_00000000-10_CUDA.cudafe1.cpp
   g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -static-libgcc -o cudar.dll tmp.def CPP.obj RcppExports.obj CUDA.obj -LC:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.3/lib/x64 -lcudart -LC:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2/bin/x64 -lR -LC:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/x64 -LC:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib -LC:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2/bin/x64 -lR
   Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?abs@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?abs@@YANN@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?abs@@YA_J_J@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?acos@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?acosh@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?asin@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?asinh@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?atan2@@YAMMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?atan@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?atanh@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?cbrt@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?ceil@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?copysign@@YAMMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?cos@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?cosh@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?erf@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?erfc@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?exp2@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?exp@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?expm1@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?fabs@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?fdim@@YAMMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?floor@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?fma@@YAMMMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?fmax@@YAMMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?fmin@@YAMMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?fmod@@YAMMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?frexp@@YAMMPEAH@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?hypot@@YAMMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?ilogb@@YAHM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?ldexp@@YAMMH@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?lgamma@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?llrint@@YA_JM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?llround@@YA_JM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?log10@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?log1p@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?log2@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?log@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?logb@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?lrint@@YAJM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?lround@@YAJM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?modf@@YAMMPEAM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?nearbyint@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?nextafter@@YAMMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?pow@@YAMMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?remainder@@YAMMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?remquo@@YAMMMPEAH@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?rint@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?round@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?scalbln@@YAMMJ@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?signbit@@YA_NM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?signbit@@YA_NN@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?signbit@@YA_NO@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?sin@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?sinh@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?sqrt@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?tan@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?tanh@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?tgamma@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ?trunc@@YAMM@Z: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export fabsf: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export frexpf: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot export ldexpf: symbol not defined
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: CUDA.obj:(.text$mn+0x10): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: CUDA.obj:(.text$mn+0x86): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
   C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: CUDA.obj:(.xdata[$unwind$getDeviceProps_CUDA]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   no DLL was created
   ERROR: compilation failed for package 'cudar'
─  removing 'C:/Users/Killian/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpMRqcYp/devtools_install_30807b7740ca/cudar'
Error in `(function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE, …`:
! System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed
---
Exit status: 1
stdout & stderr: <printed>
---
Type .Last.error to see the more details.

What's going on here?

rcpp on windows wants a host compiler from Rtools.  Unfortunately nvcc on native windows only accepts cl.exe, the compiler that ships with VS, and is not one of the supported/acceptable ones from the point of view of Rcpp.  WSL2 certainly seems like the easy button here.

Ah that's unfortunate. So if one really wanted to use it on native Windows the only solution would be to avoid Rcpp? Or might splitting the C++/Rcpp and CUDA code into separate files and compiling those individually work? As the post I mentioned (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628333/building-a-tiny-r-package-with-cuda-and-rcpp) suggested?

After some fiddling and putting C++ and CUDA into seperate files (at https://github.com/KillianMelsen/cudar/tree/split) everything seems to compile, but I'm getting an error when trying to link everything (g++.exe: error: Files/R/R-4.2.2/bin/x64: No such file or directory).
The spaces in the paths are the issue I guess. I specified the command in Makevars.win using quotes around paths, but check() overrides it:
C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk:16: warning: overriding recipe for target 'cudar.dll'
Makevars.win:21: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'cudar.dll'

It has been years but I fear you are out of luck on Windows:  CUDA insistes on its compiler (as you know), and R insists on its Rtools, and it is devilishly hard to mix Visual C++ object code wiith g++ object code.  It can be done if you wrap everything in C (not C++) foreign function calls.  Maybe not worth it -- you may have noticed by now that the other CUDA packages for R on CRAN and elsewhere usually skip Wiindows.  Kudos though for sorting your Makefile out: you did the Right Thing (TM) there but there is more.

I've been trying stuff and reading most of the day and it indeed seems practically impossible, definitely for someone with my skills. Guess I'll just stick to WSL.
I did have some hope when I remembered that I got it working before by creating a .dll using VS, putting it in an inst/lib directory within an R package, and then using dyn.load() inside that package. I tried creating that .dll using nvcc from within the Makevars but no luck either.
Did learn a lot about Makefiles and nvcc though. Thanks.

This appears to be impossible.
The Windows build infrastructure for R appears to be MinGW/gcc based. CUDA requires the Visual C++ compiler and toolchain on Windows. This fundamental difference will make interoperability basically impossible.
Your only solution seems to be to move to a platform where both CUDA and R support the same toolchain (i.e. linux).
[Answer assembled from comments and added as a community wiki entry to get the question of the unanswered question queue for the CUDA tag. Feel free to edit as you see fit]
